# Quickbooks - migrate import IIF to QODBC

Tags: quickbooks, iif, qodbc

I'm trying to migrate my actual logic to import invoices into Quickbooks using QODBC tool, and I'm having trouble finding the relationship of the columns of the IIF file with the columns of the DB.

Here is the header of my IIF file

```
!TRNS   TRNSID  TRNSTYPE    DATE    ACCNT   NAME    CLASS   AMOUNT  DOCNUM  MEMO    CLEAR   TOPRINT NAMEISTAXABLE   ADDR1   ADDR2   ADDR3   ADDR4   ADDR5   PONUM   DUEDATE TERMS   OTHER1
!SPL    SPLID   TRNSTYPE    DATE    ACCNT   NAME    CLASS   AMOUNT  DOCNUM  MEMO    CLEAR   QNTY    PRICE   INVITEM PAYMETH TAXABLE VALADJ  SERVICEDATE OTHER2  EXTRA
!ENDTRNS
```

In which tables and columns should insert data to generate an invoice with similar data that I have now?

There is some documentation where this all these relationships?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying Bait and Sync technique.

Enter something unique in customer, note, address, item, etc in the front end or the source from where you are creating the IIF file. Once the data is entered you can export it to IIF file.
Once you have that you know which fields of IIF file links to what.

You can then refer QODBC Invoice / InvoiceLine table schema/relationship.
Refer:
http://qodbc.com/schema.htm

You need to then do the field mapping, get the SQL Statement generated and execute the insert statements.

Refererences:

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2389/0/how-to-create-invoices-using-qodbc

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2810/44/how-to-insert-invoice-using-excel---vba